# Post a message to newly opened browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, addeventlistener, postmessage

I'm trying to post a message using the postMessage function to a browser that I've opened using window.open and while I've found a couple of articles explaining on how to do it:

[Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

[HTML5’s window.postMessage API](https://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage)

I just can't get it to work.

In my grid, when double clicking on a row, I call the following code:

```
var win = window.open('@Url.Action("Index", "StandaloneViewer")', '_blank', 
'width=600,height=800,scrollbars=yes');

var domainOrigin = document.location.origin;
var message = 'My Message';
win.postMessage(message, domainOrigin);
```

and in my Index.cshtml, I've got the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        debugger;
        var domainOrigin = document.origin;
        var domainPath = document.location.href;
        if (event.origin !== domainOrigin) return;
        ...
    }, false);
});
```

I've also tried the same code in the load event:

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        debugger;
        var domainOrigin = document.origin;
        var domainPath = document.location.href;
        if (event.origin !== domainOrigin) return;
        ...
    }, false);
});
```

but to no avail! Any ideas what I may be missing? I've got the same scenario working just fine when sending a message to an iframe but I have a use case where I need to launch a separate browser and send a message to it.

I'm currently testing this on the latest version of Chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use an alert or something?

Comment: I have instead of using debugger but nothing is popping up.

Comment: I usually have a script at the bottom of my view file: <script>$(document).ready(function () { alert("My Message") }); </script>

Comment: This is not my problem. Both $(document).ready and $(window).on("load...") are working as expected. The problem is that my addEventListener is not capturing the message being sent and I can't see why. From the provided articles, it seems rather straight forward and it clearly states that the window.open can be used to return the object that was opened and simply call the postMessage which then should be captured in the window that was opened but it isn't.